# How to show the adminstrator UserName in Logon Screen of Windows2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, login

How to show the adminstrator UserName in Logon Screen of Windows2008 R2 ?

I installed the  Windows2008 R2, at first it shows the adminstrator UserName in Logon Screen, but when I installed remote desktop features, it asked me to enter the UserName and Password in the Logon Screen each time.

When I uninstalled remote desktop features, it shows adminstrator UserName in Logon Screen again. Why? And How to show UserName in Logon Screen with the remote desktop features installed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this would be related to installing the .NET Framework, but can you open the Local Security Policy MMC snap-in and check this setting?

Local Policies > Security Options > Interactive Logon: Do not display last user

If you're part of a domain, you may need to check the domain policies as well.

Also, you may want to see [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/19cd48fb-a977-42b7-81d6-7b93b135d5fa/).

Comment: I have solved the problem by uninstalling the remote desktop features. But I do not know why.

Comment: Why is this a problem, logging on as the administrator shouldn't be done too often, and when done - just type it in... or use remote desktop client which will ask you first anyway...

Comment: I see you changed the question (originally it was about why installing .NET 3.5 would be affect whether the username was displayed). I have a feeling I'm misunderstanding you, but I guess if this is really a problem, I'd add the features you removed back and see if the policy I mentioned above changes. Sometimes controlled experimentation is the easiest way to figure out how something works.